# spring - jstl - Error 404 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

When I want to access on my website, I've the following error :

```
The requested resource is not available.
```

I noticed that the problem is in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file on the line `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="../../resources/normalMode/"/>` but I don't know why ?

Do you have any solutions ?

My project structure :

```
- src
  - main
    - java
      - com
        - myblog
          - controller
             -//all java files as controller
    - resources
       - normalMode
          - css
             - header.css
    - webapp
       - /WEB-INF
         - /pages 
           - mvc-dispatcher.xml
           - web.xml
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myblog.controller" />

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
              name="viewClass" />

    <property name="prefix">
      <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
      <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="../../resources/normalMode/"/>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
   "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
   "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

  <web-app>
     <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.myblog.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"","/","home"})
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init(){
         return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

Comment: For which request do you get that error? What URL?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/lbagno/

Comment: Is `lbagno` your context path? Let's see your web.xml too.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: It's done. You can see it

Comment: You haven't shown us a handler for `/lbagno`. Do you have a controller handler method mapped to `/`, for example?

Comment: 'lbagno' is the name of my project. Now, I've added my IndexController.java.

Comment: Do you have a file at `/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp`?

Comment: Yes, I have an index.jsp in WEB-INF/pages directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

to your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. With this configuration (and the component scan), Spring will scan and register your `@Controller` methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`.

With your current configuration, no such handlers were being registered and there was therefore nothing to handle your request to `/`.

Comment: I've a question. What's the difference between '<mvc:annotation-driven/>' and '<context:component-scan base-package="com.myblog.controller" />'

Comment: @user2274060 `<mvc:annotation-driven>` sets up the beans that the `DispatcherServlet` requires. It finds any beans in your context that have the `@Controller` annotation and generates handler methods for your `@RequestMapping` methods. `<context:component-scan>` scans the specified package(s) for classes annotated with `@Component` (or its sub types `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, etc.) and creates beans for them. So, you need `component-scan` to generate the beans and you need `annotation-driven` to process them.

Comment: @user2274060 I see you've asked a few questions before, but haven't accepted any answers. Consider upvoting/accepting answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to load the .xml files if you do not have them on class path

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
   classpath:spring/application-config.xml,
   /WEB-INF/conf/mvc-config.xml 
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

now you need to do the following to enable the spring mvc using annotations

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.ekiras" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <tx:annotation-driven />
```

you need to enable the annotations and component scan to scan for all the annotations in the project.

[See a demo project setup with SpringMVC + Maven + Hibernate + Sitemesh](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/02/maven-spring-mvc-hibernate-sitemesh-hello-world-project.html)